# Can i use SSH key Authentication for logging into a server which share the ssh folder?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, authentication, keys

I have 2 server systems: remoteserver1 & remoteserver2. Remoteserver2 is protected from outside login so in order for me to access it, i have to ssh into remoteserver1 and then ssh into remoteserver2. I have ssh already setup to log into remoteserver1 and it works. it doesn't ask me for a password to login. However, once i get into remoteserver1, i ssh into remoteserver2 and it will ask me for a password. So, is there anyway that i can log into remoteserver2 from remoteserver1 without the need of giving the password? Both the servers share the same home directory, so the .ssh folder is the same.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the key file you use to get into the bastion host to the `.ssh` directory (`id_rsa` / `id_dsa` file).

I'd simply suggest creating a new pair specifically for the remoteserver1 => remoteserver2 pair. Look into `ssh-keygen` to create a pair for those hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they rely on the same key pair, you can forward the ssh-agent with the `-A` switch, i.e.:

```
ssh -tA remoteserver1 ssh remoteserver2
```

Also see here for some neat `ProxyCommand` tricks.